# send a poll in telethon telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

How can i send a poll? I am trying the following code but it returns no error and the poll is not sent:

```
from typing import Optional
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.types import *
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import *

def _build_poll(question: str, *answers: str, closed: Optional[bool] = None,
                id: int = 0) -> InputMediaPoll:
    """Build a poll object."""
    return InputMediaPoll(Poll(
        id=id, question=question, answers=[
            PollAnswer(text=i, option=bytes([idx]))
            for idx, i in enumerate(answers)
        ],
        closed=closed
    ))

poll = _build_poll(f"Question", "Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3")
message = client.send_message(-325188743, file=poll)
```

Is there any better way to submit a poll with telethon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To send polls you need to construct the poll media object with the [raw API types](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/examples/word-of-warning.html) found in https://tl.telethon.dev/.

In your case, you need an example of sending would be to send a [`InputMediaPoll`](https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/input_media_poll.html) as the example shows:

```py
await client.send_message('@username',file=types.InputMediaPoll(
    poll=types.Poll(
        id=..., # type: long (random id)
        question=..., # type: string (the question)
        answers=... # type: list of PollAnswer (up to 10 answers)
    )
))
```

With actual values:

```py
from telethon.tl.types import InputMediaPoll, Poll, PollAnswer

await client.send_message("telethonofftopic",file=InputMediaPoll(
    poll=Poll(
        id=53453159,
        question="Is it 2020?",
        answers=[PollAnswer('Yes', b'1'), PollAnswer('No', b'2')]
    )
))
```

Comment: BadRequestError: RPCError 400: POLL_OPTION_INVALID (caused by SendMediaRequest)

Comment: The code you posted raises that error. Looks like `b'random_data_1'` is invalid. I have edited the answer to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

This function creates a poll on quiz mode meaning there is only one correct answer, the functions gets the following arguments:
group which is the group id or the channel id () where you want to send the quiz. In order to obtain the group id / channel id, open telegram web and turn to the old version of telegram web click on the group/channel, in the url of the web page copy for example in the url -> "https://web.telegram.org/?legacy=1#/im?p=@IntiriorChannel" the IntiriorChannel part,
if it is private group copy the number in the url for example https://web.telegram.org/?legacy=1#/im?p=s1504616337_1547258548617074964   the id is 1504616337.

the answers argument suppose to be a list of possible answers(you can have between 1 to 10 answers) for instance ["10", "20", "30", "40", "50"].

the question argument is the question you want to be asked in the quiz 
the correct_answer argument is the index+1 of the correct answer in the list of answers, for instance the correct answer is "10", then the correct_answer argument is 1, or if the answer is "40" then the correct_answer argument is 4.

```
from telethon.tl.types import Poll, PollAnswer, PollAnswerVoters,PollResults, MessageMediaPoll 
from telethon import TelegramClient 


client = TelegramClient("SessionBot", "api_id", "api_hash").start(bot_token="bot token")

async def build_quiz_poll(group: str, answers: list, question:str, correct_answer: int) -> None:
    """ Create poll in quiz mode """

    await client.send_message(group, file=MessageMediaPoll(
        poll=Poll(
            id=random.randint(0, 100_000),
            question=question,
            answers=[PollAnswer(text=option, option=bytes([i])) for i, option in
                     enumerate(answers, start=1)],
            quiz=True
        )
        results=PollResults(
            results=[PollAnswerVoters(option=bytes([correct_answer]), 
voters=200_000, correct=True)],
        )
    ))
```